# CouchDB Docker container takes 2 minutes to start

Tags: docker, couchdb, traefik

I have a project with a CouchDB container under a Traefik reverse proxy.
This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: couchdb:2
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD
labels:
  - traefik.enable=true
  - traefik.backend=couchdb
  - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:db.${APP_HOST}
  - traefik.docker.network=app-internal
  - traefik.port=5984
networks:
  - server
volumes: 
  - couchdb_data:/opt/couchdb/data
  - couchdb_config:/opt/couchdb/etc

networks:
  server:
    external:
      name: app-internal

volumes: 
  couchdb_data: {}
  couchdb_config: {}
```

I can successfully start the container with `docker-compose up -d`, but every time I make a request I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

If I run `docker-compose logs -f`, I only get:

```
Attaching to app_db_1
```

But after approximately 2 minutes I get logs like this:

```
Attaching to app_db_1
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:45.002045Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_log started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:45.006960Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application folsom started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:45.076415Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_stats started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:45.076561Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application khash started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:45.086425Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_event started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:45.095918Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application ibrowse started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:45.104024Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application ioq started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:45.106795Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application mochiweb started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:45.116667Z nonode@nohost <0.195.0> -------- Apache CouchDB 2.1.2 is starting.
db_1      | 
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:45.119537Z nonode@nohost <0.196.0> -------- Starting couch_sup
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:45.366272Z nonode@nohost <0.47.0> -------- alarm_handler: {set,{system_memory_high_watermark,[]}}
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:46.174267Z nonode@nohost <0.195.0> -------- Apache CouchDB has started. Time to relax.
db_1      | 
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:46.174398Z nonode@nohost <0.195.0> -------- Apache CouchDB has started on http://any:5986/
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:46.174571Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:46.174743Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application ets_lru started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:46.287113Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application rexi started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [error] 2018-07-29T04:38:46.341609Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.265.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{ets,member,[mem3_openers,<<11 bytes>>],[]},{mem3_shards,maybe_spawn_shard_writer,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,486}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,389}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk... 
db_1      | [error] 2018-07-29T04:38:46.342196Z nonode@nohost <0.248.0> -------- Error opening view group `_replicator` from database `shards/80000000-9fffffff/_replicator.1532833386`: {'EXIT',{{badmatch,{badarg,[{ets,member,[mem3_openers,<<"_replicator">>],[]},{mem3_shards,maybe_spawn_shard_writer,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,486}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,389}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,378}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,407}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,96}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{couch_index_server,'-get_index/3-fun-0-',2,[{file,"src/couch_index_server.erl"},{line,68}]}]}},[{couch_mrview,get_info,2,[{file,"src/couch_mrview.erl"},{line,332}]},{couch_compaction_daemon,maybe_compact_view,3,[{file,"src/couch_compaction_daemon.erl"},{line,253}]},{couch_compaction_daemon,maybe_compact_views,3,[{file,"src/couch_compaction_daemon.erl"},{line,227}]},{couch_compaction_daemon,'-compact_loop/1-fun-0-',3,[{file,"src/couch_compaction_daemon.erl"},{line,141}]},{couch_server,'-all_databases/2-fun-0-',4,[{file,"src/couch_server.erl"},{line,278}]},{filelib,do_fold_files2,8,[{file,"filelib.erl"},{line,184}]},{filelib,do_fold_files2,8,[{file,"filelib.erl"},{line,194}]},{couch_server,all_databases,2,[{file,"src/couch_server.erl"},{line,267}]}]}}
db_1      | [error] 2018-07-29T04:38:46.730749Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.310.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{ets,member,[mem3_openers,<<6 bytes>>],[]},{mem3_shards,maybe_spawn_shard_writer,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,486}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,389}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk... 
db_1      | [error] 2018-07-29T04:38:46.732051Z nonode@nohost <0.248.0> -------- Error opening view group `_auth` from database `shards/40000000-5fffffff/_users.1532833374`: {'EXIT',{{badmatch,{badarg,[{ets,member,[mem3_openers,<<"_users">>],[]},{mem3_shards,maybe_spawn_shard_writer,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,486}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,389}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,378}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,407}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,96}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{couch_index_server,'-get_index/3-fun-0-',2,[{file,"src/couch_index_server.erl"},{line,68}]}]}},[{couch_mrview,get_info,2,[{file,"src/couch_mrview.erl"},{line,332}]},{couch_compaction_daemon,maybe_compact_view,3,[{file,"src/couch_compaction_daemon.erl"},{line,253}]},{couch_compaction_daemon,maybe_compact_views,3,[{file,"src/couch_compaction_daemon.erl"},{line,227}]},{couch_compaction_daemon,'-compact_loop/1-fun-0-',3,[{file,"src/couch_compaction_daemon.erl"},{line,141}]},{couch_server,'-all_databases/2-fun-0-',4,[{file,"src/couch_server.erl"},{line,278}]},{filelib,do_fold_files2,8,[{file,"filelib.erl"},{line,184}]},{filelib,do_fold_files2,8,[{file,"filelib.erl"},{line,194}]},{couch_server,all_databases,2,[{file,"src/couch_server.erl"},{line,267}]}]}}
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:46.792070Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application mem3 started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:46.792258Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application fabric started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.038648Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application chttpd started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.058860Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_index started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.058951Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_mrview started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.058997Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_plugins started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.078801Z nonode@nohost <0.373.0> -------- Opening index for db: _users idx: _design/_auth sig: "3e823c2a4383ac0c18d4e574135a5b08"
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.183364Z nonode@nohost <0.404.0> -------- Opening index for db: _replicator idx: _design/_replicator sig: "3e823c2a4383ac0c18d4e574135a5b08"
db_1      | [notice] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.267666Z nonode@nohost <0.82.0> -------- config: [features] scheduler set to true for reason nil
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.301691Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_replicator started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.316926Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_peruser started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.340586Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application ddoc_cache started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.359635Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application global_changes started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.359675Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application jiffy started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.369212Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application mango started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.373713Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application setup started on node nonode@nohost
db_1      | [info] 2018-07-29T04:38:47.373771Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application snappy started on node nonode@nohost
```

After that, I can successfully make requests to the database

I have tested many times and it always takes almost 2 minutes.

Does someone know why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I ran it without Traefik I still have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I'm coming late to this one, but I encountered the very same issue today while creating a script to help test my CouchDB backups. After some investigation I discovered that the source of the delay was a line in the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script which updates the ownership of files in the `/opt/couchdb` tree in the container. This is the line:

```
find /opt/couchdb \! \( -user couchdb -group couchdb \) -exec chown -f couchdb:couchdb '{}' +
```

This command has to update over 1600 files during the first startup of the container. Which, depending on your container host and the host file system, can take some time.

Until the CouchDB project fixes this issue, you can derive your own optimized container using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM couchdb:latest

RUN find /opt/couchdb \! \( -user couchdb -group couchdb \) -exec chown -c couchdb:couchdb '{}' +
```

Using this container image as the base for my test containers I was able to reduce the initial startup time from > 50 seconds down to 3 seconds.